# nested calls to printf

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   printf("%d", printf("%d",printf("Hello world!\n")));
}
```

Why this gives output as 132 ? hello world is 13 units long.

Comment: Please use a proper title, don't just put the code in the title.

Comment: sorry i am new here..I'm changing the title

Comment: A proper title... "Can't understand a C Code" is too generic.

Comment: You're printing characters as integers.  What do you expect it to print?  The length of the string?

Comment: @Matt actually, it does not print characters at all. It does print the return value of the `printf()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to see what's happening more clearly if you split the statement into several statements:

```
int temp1 = printf("Hello world!\n");
int temp2 = printf("%d", temp1);
printf("%d", temp2);
```

The first `printf` prints `Hello world!\n`. Since this is 13 characters, it returns `13`.

The second `printf` prints `13`. Since this is 2 characters, it returns `2`.

The third `printf` prints `2`.

So the full output will be:

```
Hello world!
132
```

It would have been more obvious what's going on if you added more newlines:

```
printf("%d\n", printf("%d\n",printf("Hello world!\n")));
```

would print:

```
Hello world!
13
3
```

Comment: thank you, i got it. I thought it was one hundred and thirty two.

Comment: It would have been less confusing if you put spaces or newlines after the numbers.

Comment: actually it's returning   Hello world!                                                                                                                   
13                                                                                                                             
3  is it for the new line ?

Comment: @DhrubaGoswami Yep, you're getting the hang of it now :) I think that last 2 was just a typo here.

Comment: @Lundin Not a typo, just forgot that the change would have a secondary effect, I hadn't actually tried it.

Answer (score 2):

open `man 3 printf` and check what it returns

> Upon  successful  return,  these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null
>          byte used to end output to strings).

In your case `printf("Hello world!\n")` 1st it prints `Hello world!` and then returns no of printable char which is `13` and again it prints `2` as `13` has `2` char.